# Is there a way to do a left align on a form in Rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Please reference the project here at this URL

[solanosprinklers.net](http://solanosprinklers.net)

I was able to get the form centered inside the span by using :style =>"margin-left:-30%"

I used the negative margin , becaise frankly, thats the only thing that finally worked. Now it looks good on a full screen, but once it collapses down to tablet and Phone resolution, the text fields stick outside of the "span". I need help to properly do this.

ALSO, how can i get that gray background that is behind the "send"button , out of there ?

Form layout .....\layouts\indexform

```
<%= form_for @customer, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal',:style =>'margin-left:-30%'} do |f| %>
    <div class="control-group">

    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :cust_fname, :class => 'text_field',:style => 'float: left', :placeholder =>"First Name" %>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">

    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :cust_lname, :class => 'text_field', :placeholder =>"Last Name" %>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">

    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :cust_phone, :class => 'text_field', :placeholder =>"Phone" %>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">

    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :cust_email, :class => 'text_field', :placeholder =>"Email" %>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">

    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.radio_button :cust_property,'Residential', :class => 'radio_button' %> Residential
      <%= f.radio_button :cust_property,'Commercial', :class => 'radio_button' %> Commercial
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">

    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_area :cust_notes, :class => 'text_area', :placeholder =>"How can we help ?" %>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Send", :class => 'btn btn-primary',:style => "background:green" %>

    </div>
<% end %>
```

index.html.erb  .....where the form is rendered.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <div style="border: 5px solid;border-radius: 15px">
                <h3 style="text-align:center">Let us know how we can help</h3>
                <hr>
                 <div > 
                    <%= render "layouts/indexform"%>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
            <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <div>
            <%= image_tag 'Sprinkler2.png' %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <hr>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <h3>Our Preferred Systems</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4" style="padding-bottom:10px">
            <%= image_tag 'rainbird.png' %>
        </div>

        <div class="span4" style="padding-bottom:10px">
            <%= image_tag 'toro.png' %>
        </div>

        <div class="span4" style="padding-bottom:10px">
            <%= image_tag 'hunter.png' %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i checked url.
try this:

```
<div class="">
<%= f.submit "Send", :class => 'btn btn-primary',:style => "background:green" %>

</div>
```

just update class="form-actions" to class=""

and then :

```
<div class="">
<%= f.submit "Send", :class => 'btn btn-primary',:style => "background:green;position:absolute;left=300px;" %>

</div>
```

Comment: Do I should leave the Quotes empty ? Just wondering,  how does removing "form-actions"  allow the styling to function properly ?

Comment: Also, I am really trying to figure out how to keep the form left aligned in all views.....right now it just works in fullscreen view. The text fields overlap in tablet and phone views

Comment: i visited your url and did this in inspect element and it worked

Comment: yes,its likes that you download all source of url and test on your system.

Comment: rightclick on screan and select Inspect Element.it shows all html,js,css codes

Comment: the form that you see ion the main page is not responsive when viewed on Tablet or phone. Would you happen to know  to handle that now that I have left aligned the form ?